# C#: the fastest array for billions of calculations

Tags: c#, performance, types

Would it be char, byte, Int16, Int32, Int64 (maybe last three unsigned, since I wouldn't have negative numbers?).

I need it for multiplication and adding. The smaller numbers can contain a type, the more parts a big number will be divided into.

```
An example: 1234567898765321
In char: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
In Int32: {123456789, 87654321}
```

So, which is faster to use for billions of calculations?

Comment: An array reference variable is still a variable. It doesn't matter.

Comment: But I can have more calculations if using char type (maybe faster) or having less calculations using int32 type (can hold bigger numbers, maybe faster)

Comment: Your missing the point. The array itself is not have any bearing on branch prediction.

Comment: Randolph ... please see [Processing a Sorted Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) for more info.

Comment: But I have to do it this way. Is there any other "normal" way to add to 1 million-digit numbers? I don't think so. Then I have to use arrays. Numerical, for the best performance. I can split these great numbers into smaller (one element - one digit) or a bit bigger (one element - 4 digits). Is there a difference?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19750/discussion-between-eddie-b-and-randolph)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean:

> Can I get a speed advantage by splitting large numbers into small
>   pieces and doing my own carrying logic for addition and
>   multiplication?

The answer is no. Use types that are large enough to hold the entire value, and the compiler/JIT will generate machine code that does each arithmetic operation in a single instruction, which will be as fast as possible.

Comment: It's exactly what I mean. But what if I have a number that has 100.000 digits? I must have some splits.

Comment: @Randolph: Then use `BigInteger`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant. I have to write my own arithmetic without it.

Comment: @Randolph - as an academic exercise? Then you should do your homework yourself and find out which is fastest! :p

Comment: Not an academic, rather a theory that would be used for everything I'll be doing for the academic exercises :) I did some benchmark. From it, Int32 was faster than Int64 and both faster than char. But to be sure, I would have to write different functions, each having other idea. So before it, I just wanted to ask.

Comment: Did you have any theories for why Int32 was faster than Int64? What hardware were you running on?

Comment: Another option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894696/how-to-use-gpu-for-mathematics

Comment: Intel i7, 2.93 GHz. It just was faster :) If I have, let's say, a two numbers 12345678987654321, it was faster to add 1234567 + 1234567 and 8987654321 + 8987654321 than these two numbers right away.

Comment: @Randolph computers are designed to understand two numbers; zero and one ... learn up about binary math and this _might_ become clearer.